# Ruby on Rails: REST API + file upload + paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest, paperclip

I'm trying to upload an attachment using REST API on my server through a PUT request. I can do this by putting the binary file in the request body but I'd also like to save this file as an attachment to a model which uses paperclip to save attachments.

Here's my current involved class definitions:

```
class Cl < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :save_tses
  validates_associated :tses

  has_many :tses

  ...truncated...

  def save_tses
    tses.each do |ts|
      ts.save(false)
    end
  end

end

class Ts < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :tsa, :styles => { :thumb => {:geometry => "100x141>", :format => :jpg} }, 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:friendly_filename",
    :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:friendly_filename"

  belongs_to :cl

  def friendly_filename
    "#{self.tsa_file_name.gsub( /[^a-zA-Z0-9_\.]/, '_')}" 
  end
end
```

I can save the attachments just fine using the file upload on the html page. I'd like to do this on a controller that receives the file as binary data through a PUT request.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

```
# controller.rb

def add_ts
  # params[:id]
  # params[:tsa]

  @cl = Cl.find(params[:id])
  ts = @cl.tses.build(:name => "#{@cl.name}_#{Time.now.to_i}")

  ts.tsa = params[:tsa]
  if ts.save
    render :json => {:status => "OK"}
  else
    render :json => {:status => "ERROR"}
  end
end

# Test

curl -F "tsa=@file.pdf" "http://host/cl/474/add_ts"
=> {"status":"OK"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can you use -
https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty