# iOS Client + Rest API to upload photos

Tags: ios, web-services, rest

I have a basic requirement of uploading an image from an iOS App to a remote server. I know that I can use `NSURLConnection` to transfer the image to a remote server but I need to develop a REST Webservice also in the remote server which can accept images from the iOS Client and store inside a DB/hard disk .

Can anyone please suggest me the best method/libraries which can be used to  to develop the REST Webservice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) with the [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem.
If it's completely new to you, you can start with the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).
There's a lot of material on how to build a RESTful API with Rails, like [this screencast](http://gavinmorrice.com/blog/posts/21-building-a-restful-api-in-rails-3).
Once you've understood how to develop an API, and how to use Paperclip to save images on the server, the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241709/ruby-on-rails-rest-api-file-upload-paperclip) might help you with the file upload part.

Comment: Can you please suggest me a method to do the same in Java ? Is jersey a good one ?

Comment: Hmm you could use Spring http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html - It will have better performance probably (if done right) but it will definitely take a lot more work, in my experience...