# Upload file using input tag(without rails/html form) and paperclip in rails

Tags: ajax, paperclip, input-type-file

I am a kind of new on ROR, I want to upload an image using simple input tag and don't want to use form for that. The basic functionality of Paperclip is known to me. If I am not wrong then the format of object that is being passed to save image is :

```
"image_object"=>
  [#< ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb5ad25f4
    @content_type="image/gif",
    @headers=
     "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pic[]\"; filename=\"test.gif\"\r\nContent-Type: image/gif\r\n",
    @original_filename="test.gif",
    @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131112-17750-1lprijc>>]
```

I want to upload image using the following steps:
1. Using Jquery, I want to fetch the appropriate details(file parameter) of selected image in input tag and send those using Jquery/ajax.
2. By passing that parameters to rails controller I want to use those details to generate an object(as sample shown above) that can be used to save Image in my application.

My questions are:
1. which Jquery method should I use and what are the parameters that are necessary to generate the image object?
2. On controller side, how to generate Image Object using those details?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to upload file through RESTApi ?

Comment: Yes I am doing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right. But based on the details you provided there are many options you can go for.

The simplest one is as follows:

Just add `:remote => true` to the rails form and submit the form and on the controller side you can create the object.

But if you want to be able to upload an image through a REST API then [this link](http://shawndeprey.blogspot.in/2013/05/puting-image-uploads-using-paperclip.html) should help.

You can visit the SO question as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241709/ruby-on-rails-rest-api-file-upload-paperclip) which describes exactly what u want.